# when submit the from it goes to the wrong route using laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

when i have tried to submit the login form it goes to the logout route with `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error and no message

```
// this is my route
Route::get('/',function(){return view('users.home');});
Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('showRegister');
Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register')->name('Register');
Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('showLogin');
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login');
```

and this is my login and logout controller

```
 public function login(loginRequest $request )
{

    if ( Auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->Username, 'password' => $request->Password], $request->remember) ) {
        return redirect()->intended( url('dashboard') );
    }// Authentication failed, redirect back to the login form
    return redirect($this->redirect);
}

/**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    Auth::guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->flush();
    return redirect()->guest(route('showLogin'));
}
```

Comment: and this is my login form action    <form method="POST" action="{{route('login')}}">

Comment: Is `$this->redirect` the route that you're being redirected to?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `redirect($this->redirect)` use `Redirect::back()`

```php
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
```

and in your login controller function

```php
public function login(loginRequest $request )
{

if ( Auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->Username, 'password' => $request->Password], $request->remember) ) {
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}// Authentication failed, redirect back to the login form
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
}
```

and inside your view call this

```php
@if($errors->any())
  <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
```

Comment: you have error in your redirect to dashboard. please check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

redirect in login controller is wrong

```
     public function login(loginRequest $request )
    {
    if ( Auth()->attempt(['email' => $request->Username, 'password' => $request- 
    >Password], $request->remember) ) {
    //return redirect()->intended( url('dashboard') );
   // the correct answer is
    return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
    return redirect($this->redirect);
```